# Creating maps programmatically using ArcObjects. Adding legends, scale bars, north arrows?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, cartography

I'm looking for some examples related to the publishing of maps programmatically to image format using ArcObjects. More specifically I would like to add standard map elements such as a scale bar, legend, and north arrow.

Currently I am able to create an MXD, add several layers from paths stored in a dictionary, set the symbology based on layer files, set the extent, and export the map as a JPEG. Up to this point I haven't found any examples of ArcObjects code that also makes the map look more professional by adding additional elements (and sizing/positioning them).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Working with the page layout](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_the_page_layout/000100000126000000/) section in the documentation - mainly the [Map surrounds](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Map_surrounds/00010000043m000000/) topic, which provides an overview how the most common map surrounds (legend, scalebar etc.) are structured, followed by [Working with map surrounds](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_map_surrounds/0001000001zw000000/), which shows how to add these elements to the page layout.

Comment: This is perfect - I've never heard the term 'map surrounds' used before in the context of ArcMap.